# Lazy load children of childrens (EF)

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

Is there a way to make a multiple level lazy load?

If I have Grandfather > Sons > grandsons, I'm able to do `Grandfather.Sons.Load();`

how can I lazy load grandsons too? (I don't want to use eager loading)

do I have to loop through all sons or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Grandfather.Sons.CreateSourceQuery()
                .Include("Grandsons")
                .ToList();
```

It will use eager loading in your lazy loaded `Son`.